# How do I add a node ID as class to the <body> tag?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7, there is a class like path-node-NID (with NID replaced by the node ID of the node being viewed) added to the `<body>` tag so we can easily add CSS styles to specific nodes. This is missing in Drupal 8.

How can I add the node ID as CSS class to the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Drupal 8 is missing this core D7 functionality, but now there is a module for that, its called [Body node ID class](https://www.drupal.org/project/body_node_id_class)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **mytheme.theme** file: add the below code.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Add node ID to the body class.
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if (is_object($node)) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->id();
  }
}
```

This will add "node-{{nid}}" class in body tag.

**Another Option**

You can try [Node Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_class) module as well.

> Node Class is a simple module that allows users to add custom CSS
> classes to any node through the node/add interface.

Comment: For new user of drupal, you have to replace `mytheme_` in function name with the name of the theme, if the theme name is comets, then :  `function comets_preprocess_html()`

Comment: To be extra careful, you could check if $node is a node rather than just an object with`$node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface` instead of `is_object($node)`

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comment made by @hockey2112, the accepted answer throws an error when viewing revisions. The code below is more reliable.

In mytheme.theme file: add the below code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
   // Add node id to the body class.
   $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
   if(is_object($node)) {
     $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->id();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those you might still be looking for this on Drupal 9, you may check out this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/body_node_id_class

Comment: Rather copy the five lines of code then install another module for that. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/body_node_id_class/-/blob/8.x-1.x/body_node_id_class.module