# Add an attribute to $variables from a Controller

Tags: 8, nodes

I need to add an attribute to the body tag from a controller. Adding a body tag with `hook_preprocess_HOOK()` is not a problem.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'my.route') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
  }
}
```

However, I only want to add the attribute when the node object, which is already in the controller, meets a second condition which is:

```
if ((\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'my.route') && ($this->moderationInformation->hasPendingRevision($node))) {}
```

I don't have `$variables` in the controller so how can this be done?

Comment: You didn't provide any details about the custom route, but since it points to a controller displaying a node object it should contain the node as a route parameter, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220301/how-do-i-add-a-node-id-as-class-to-the-body-tag

Comment: It turns out we didn't have to add a body tag, which allowed for a this simple addition to the build:    
    `$build += [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['class' => 'my-class'],
    ];`

Leaving the question open for now since I would still like to know how to add a body tag from the controller. Remember that we're on the controller here. A hook won't help in this case.

Comment: To further clarify, we're in the controller, which is on a route, obviously. A preprocess hook won't help because although the route has the node object, we're not on a node.

Answer (score 2):

Rendered output from a controller or other page elements like blocks or menus don't have direct access to the variables of a page/html preprocess hook. You can however attach metadata to the render array which then bubbles up to the page level when rendered, for example html_head or css libraries. In your case one possible way would be to attach a placeholder to the render array of the controller, which then replaces a placeholder class in the body tag. But I still would prefer to get the node via the route parameter, see the linked topic in the first comment.

A code example how to replace a body tag class from a controller. First add a placeholder class in the preprocess hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for html.html.twig.
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'body-placeholder-class';
}
```

And then attach a placeholder to the build array to replace this class from the controller:

```
$build['#attached'] = [
  'placeholders' => [
    'body-placeholder-class' => [
      '#markup' => 'class-replaced-by-controller',
    ],
  ],
];
return $build;
```