# How do I pass a CSS class to the controller?

Tags: page-controller

I want to pass a CSS class to a controller.

In the case of nodes, I am using the following code.

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->id();
}
```

Is there any way to pass a CSS class to a generic controller?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you are asking. You have full control of what markup your controller outputs. Maybe you can show us a simplified version of your controller and explain in what situations exactly you want to add a CSS class (dynamically)?

Comment: Different controllers have different parameters you can get from the route match. Or do you want to pass a body class from a controller? Then see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/265937/add-an-attribute-to-variables-from-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use this helper function to get entity from page :
Posted on Drupal Forum [get_page_entity](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2014-07-25/drupal-8-get-entity-object-given#comment-12752478)

- Hook implementation.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
     */
    function YourThemeName_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
      //- Call Helper function.
      $entity = get_page_entity();
     if($entity) {
        $variables['attributes']->addClass($entity->getEntityTypeId() . '-' . $entity->id());
      }
    }
```

- Helper Function.

```
    use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
    /**
     * @return array|bool|\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface|mixed|null
     */
    function get_page_entity() {
      $page_entity = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, NULL);
      if (isset($page_entity)) {
        return $page_entity ?: NULL;
      }
      $current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
      foreach ($current_route->getParameters() as $param) {
        if ($param instanceof EntityInterface) {
          $page_entity = $param;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!isset($page_entity)) {
        // Some routes don't properly define entity parameters.
        // Thus, try to load them by its raw Id, if given.
        $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
        $types = $entity_type_manager->getDefinitions();
        foreach ($current_route->getParameters()->keys() as $param_key) {
          if (!isset($types[$param_key])) {
            continue;
          }
          if ($param = $current_route->getParameter($param_key)) {
            if (is_string($param) || is_numeric($param)) {
              try {
                $page_entity = $entity_type_manager->getStorage($param_key)
                  ->load($param);
              } catch (\Exception $e) {
              }
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!isset($page_entity) || !$page_entity->access('view')) {
        $page_entity = FALSE;
        return NULL;
      }
      return $page_entity;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement  [template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x)  something like this:

```
function YourThemeName_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if($node) {
    $variables['attributes']->addClass('node-' . $node->id());
  }
}
```

Comment: i want this for all controllers route, not for node type.