# hook_views_post_execute() don't work on AJAX View with exposed filters after 1st refresh

Tags: views, ajax

I have a View which returns 5 entities of the same type. AJAX - enabled, filters and exposed filters, all working fine.

I need to add a new result, a user - defined entity, at the top of the View results. This programmatically added row should not be affected when the exposed filters are used and should remain at the top of the View, on top of the other 5 returned results, no matter what.

I managed to add this with hook_views_post_execute() but when I use the exposed filters the View returns to its original results and my addition is lost, because AJAX is enabled on this View. `hook_views_post_execute()` doesn't seem to have any effect after the initial page load.

What is a good alternative for this scenario ie alter the View in a way that's not affected by the AJAX refresh?

Comment: In the UI you can embed a different view into the header area of your view. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Attachments and headers also disappear on AJAX refresh.

Comment: Make views exposed form as block, make user result views as block. Place these blocks above of View with 5 entities. That's all...

Comment: @nikit the View structure needs to stay as is, not break it down into blocks as this will also create a huge need for theming changes. 
The required solution is to inject the one “independent of filters” entity between the filters and the dynamic results and make it unaffected by any change coming from the exposed filters.

Comment: @webmaniac I don't think that's big problem for theming changes - exposed block and view will have one common classes. Also you can assign class in view settings. The same for users view.

Comment: @nikit it's not that straight forward like adding a block to a region. This View is rendered in a nested entities structure and it's also used elsewhere, on other pages, as is. Changing everything to blocks would create 10 times the work needed to get this working.

Comment: If you can't get it working in a hook you can alter the ajax commands updating the view in an event subscriber, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282054/fetch-view-results-from-mymodule-preprocess-page-hook

Comment: @4k4 would I be able to re-calculate the entity (from the current path where this View exists) inside the Event subscriber ie on an AJAX change of the results, would the current routeMatch still be the one where this View lives?

Comment: No, Views has a separate Ajax endpoint `views/ajax`.

Comment: Exactly, @4k4. So the problem is how to get the node this View is displayed on, inside that EventSubscriberInterface implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: I have an idea, I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking the current route match in a Views Ajax request you get the route of the Views Ajax endpoint `views/ajax` and not the route of the page where the View is placed on.

However, Ajax requests contain the original path of the View and `ViewAjaxController::ajaxView()` puts this path in the global current path stack (for the pager to work correctly).

So if the path is no longer in the request

```
$path = \Drupal::request()->request->get('view_path');
```

it should be transfered to:

```
$path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
```

Which should then point to the node route you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this returns /views/ajax.

I think I'm getting somewhere with \Drupal::request()->server->get('HTTP_REFERER') and \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost().

Comment: You can't rely on the refererer, not all clients provide one. If `view_path` is not transferred already to the current path it should still be present in the request.

Comment: 4k4 can you elaborate please, I don't seem to get anythign in view_path.

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(); still returns /views/ajax.

Comment: Given that I can get the path from HTTP_REFERER, how would I load the entity using the command? Something like $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#entity-wrapper', $entity)); doesn't work. What format should I render the entity in the AJAX command? I can see mostly form elements being loaded that way, not whole entities. I'm using something like $build = $view_builder->view($entity, $view_mode); but that doesn't work.

Comment: I had now a chance to xdebug the code. It works and returns the original path of the View. The reason it is not working for you might be because you have multiple level of View Ajax so that the original View is already delivered by another ajaxified View.

Comment: 4k4 there are no multiple levels of View AJAX here. This View is coming from a rendered Views reference field inside a paragraph inside the top level node. Perhaps the Views reference is altering the behaviour somehow but mo multiple levels of AJAX. Re - HTTP_REFERER, wouldn’t be relatively safe to use, given that the referrer in this case would always represent the node this Views lives in? This is not a case of a getting the referrer for an non AJAX request so the origin for this AJAX request will always be the top level node.

Comment: I can't debug your application from afar. I would use the browser debugging tools to see what the client is sending and receiving. You can also use the superglobal $_POST server side to see whether the original view path is in the request. Don't use the referer, this is not working in a real world scenario.

Comment: I didn't ask you to. I'm accepting your answer though it doesn't solve my particular problem probably because of how Views reference renders this View. Something in there makes the View forget its path. Your answer would possibly help with a more generic instance which might still be helpful to some, hence accepting it. Thanks for yoru time.